# Count the number of inversions using Binary Indexed Tree in an array

Tags: python, algorithm, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

[Original Problem: HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insertion-sort)

I am trying to count the number of inversions using Binary Indexed Tree in an array. I've tried to optimise my code as much as I can. However, I still got TLE for the last 3 test cases. Any ideas that I can further optimise my code?

```
# Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT
#!/usr/bin/python

from copy import deepcopy



class BinaryIndexedTree(object):
    """Binary Indexed Tree
    """
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n + 1
        self.bit = [0] * self.n

    def update(self, i, k):
        """Adds k to element with index i
        """
        while  i <= self.n - 1:
            self.bit[i] += k
            i = i + (i & -i)

    def count(self, i):
        """Returns the sum from index 1 to i
        """
        total = 0
        while i > 0:
            total += self.bit[i]
            i = i - (i & -i)
        return total


def binary_search(arr, target):
    """Binary Search
    """
    left, right = 0, len(arr) - 1
    while left <= right:
        mid = left + ((right - left) >> 1)
        if target == arr[mid]:
            return mid
        elif target < arr[mid]:
            right = mid - 1
        else:
            left = mid + 1

    # If not found, return -1.
    return -1


T = input()
for iterate in xrange(T):
    n = input()
    q = [ int( i ) for i in raw_input().strip().split() ]
    answer = 0
    # Write code to compute answer using x, a and answer

    # Build a Binary Indexed Tree.
    bit = BinaryIndexedTree(n)

    # Copy q and sort it.
    arr = sorted(deepcopy(q))

    # index array.
    index = map(lambda t: binary_search(arr, t) + 1, q)

    # Loop.
    for i in xrange(n - 1, -1, -1):
        answer += bit.count(index[i])
        bit.update(index[i] + 1, 1)
    print answer
```

Comment: Does `#!/usr/bin/python` even work if it's not on the first line of the file?

Comment: @Mast It'll not work if you run that on your local machine using `./` to your script name. I guess that's just a prompt (the first line) of HackerRank online editor, and HackerRank will take care of running it correctly behind the scene.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     def __init__(self, n):
>         self.n = n + 1
>         self.bit = [0] * self.n
> ```

`bit` has a well-known interpretation in programming which distracts from the intended interpretation here. IMO even something as generic as `data` would be better.

---

> ```
>     def update(self, i, k):
>         """Adds k to element with index i
>         """
>         while  i <= self.n - 1:
>             self.bit[i] += k
>             i = i + (i & -i)
> ```

The loop condition would be more familiar as `while i < self.n`.

I don't see any reason to avoid `+=`.

A reference to explain the data structure would be helpful, because otherwise this is quite mysterious.

---

> ```
>         mid = left + ((right - left) >> 1)
> ```

The reason for this particular formulation of the midpoint is to avoid overflow in languages with fixed-width integer types. Since that's not an issue in Python, I'd favour the more straightforward `mid = (left + right) >> 1`. It might even be a tiny bit faster.

---

> ```
>     q = [ int( i ) for i in raw_input().strip().split() ]
> ```

> ```
>     index = map(lambda t: binary_search(arr, t) + 1, q)
> ```

Why the inconsistency? I think it would be more Pythonic to use comprehensions for both.

---

> ```
>     # Copy q and sort it.
>     arr = sorted(deepcopy(q))
>
>     # index array.
>     index = map(lambda t: binary_search(arr, t) + 1, q)
> ```

This seems like a rather heavyweight approach. Why not just

```
    index = sorted((val, idx) for idx, val in enumerate(q))
```

?

---

Although asymptotically I don't see any reason why this would be \$\omega(n \lg n)\$, it has a few \$\Theta(n \lg n)\$ stages. The standard algorithm for this problem, which is essentially merge sort, has the same asymptotic complexity but probably hides a much smaller constant behind the \$\Theta\$ / \$O\$.

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty sure you can replace

```
def count(self, i):
    """Returns the sum from index 1 to i
    """
    total = 0
    while i > 0:
        total += self.bit[i]
        i = i - (i & -i)
    return total
```

with

```
def count(self, i):
    return sum(self.bit[i] for i in range(1,i))
```

also,

```
mid = left + ((right - left) >> 1)
```

is the same as

```
mid = (right + left) >> 1
```

Comment: Not sure which of the docstring (and thus your interpretation) or the original code is wrong, but `while i > 0: i = i - (i & -i)` is _NOT_ the same as `range(1, i)`.

Comment: I think it's a docstring problem, what do you want `i - (i & -i)` to do?

Comment: I don't want it to do anything, it's just not performing `i -> 1`. For instance, with `i = 31` it goes `31 -> 30 -> 28 -> 24 -> 16 -> 0`: it removes the least significant bit at each iteration.

Comment: oh. Then for the first piece, all I'd change is `i=i-...` to `i-=...`